# Changing a string in an .exe file

Tags: scripting

I would like to know how to change a String in an .exe file. It is a list of 8 files which have all the same Content but are used in diferent paths. And These paths (Folders) are named 1-8. And now I have to Change that string ("word class 1") into 2-8 ("word class 2, ...") I did it manually with Notepad++ for a week now but it's time consuming and I don't want to do it anymore with Notepad++. :)

I don't mind any way of a solution to this Problem so, that's it. 
I tried it with powershell so far but I can't figure out how to get the solution done with the get-content & select_string but it didn't work out as intended.

Thank you for reading and answering my question. (sorry for some typos)

Comment: this doesn't really seem like a programming question, but rather an one time task. you should be able to use any hex editor for that. be advised this only works if the two strings are exactly the same length, as you're messing up the addresses else.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should also have written that it should be used for more then 1 file and once a day so it should be a script or something I don't have to use all the time manually.

Comment: maybe you might want to tell us what you're actually trying to achieve, cause "change some strings about 'word classes' in some exe files once a day" pretty much seems like "make my english teacher believe i passed the vocab learning tool's tests" ;) also, messing around in foreign binary should be avoided if there's another option, so just tell us what you're trying to do?

Comment: also maybe edit your question, because you don't want "to know IF it's possible in any way", you should already know it is. because that's what computers do: take some data from somewhere->mess with it->put it back somewhere. you want to know "HOW". and also PLEASE specify your environment, cause it matters much which OS it is, what tools are installed, if you need root access (and if you have it), etc.

Comment: ok, and now please tell us what you're actually trying to achieve, because you said yourself editing them manually is bad, and editing them automatically is only a quick and dirty way to save you some time, not a better solution, which is what you should consider seeking instead if possible imho.

Comment: => what are those files, where do they come from (=why can't you just edit their source or copy the fixed versions over from a backup, etc), and why do you need those strings changed (=what do those strings affect which you want to do)

Comment: The files are programms. And I have to Change them everyday because they get updated every day and they Change the code always to default but I need to run them simultaniously and thats why I have to use that Kind of System. And the effect is just that I can run that Programm in 8 instances.

Comment: a) i know they're programs, cause you said they're exes. what do those programs do? ; b) you can happily run the same exe in multiple instances, so no, that's not why you're doing it.

Comment: They use the same .dat file but you can let that .dat file be shared with the Parameter -shareArchive but you can't open more then one instance even if you share it cause the Programm blocks that. And that's why I Need These changes in the programms .exe.

Comment: ok, so now we at least know the program is actively blocking you. now maybe FINALLY tell us WHAT program you're trying to use. also, as expected, this is NOT a programming question but a "how do i prevent program X from using a session manager/whatever it is that tries to block you?"-question, which is usually answered by a) the manual or b) the developer's forum or c) torturing the developer -_-

Answer (score -1):

You just want to replace some values within a .exe?

This is how I'd do it.

You need to provide a CSV file, first column titled OLD, second column titled new.

Here is my fake .exe file I made:

```
7deeadc7-a2b3-4c47-8cf6-61f09d986977ham
d1ea8982-4a04-4f2b-8e5a-244965921fccsam
b4a8f37a-c607-405b-8493-9b9b0e79673btam
0922496b-3064-4958-a6b0-46f61a711860turkey
e5f30554-e50e-4b61-aaa3-3797d9e0ed5ccheese
82e3d77f-53d5-49ef-bf84-b872dbbe556ffork
60a01cad-f6c4-44cc-af1a-fafb20377a12rice
e2cd71a1-7c34-456f-9af4-924f79874c38yummy
c85da055-c47e-41be-a0f8-5c320fa05317linux
7dbee5fc-87d5-4900-80c5-00818514d5b4morp
d9941dfe-dd97-422d-9088-2cecf4904fdepoo
05eaf9b3-09a2-45ea-b9a0-4c78ff9156f2pot
8c75d00d-4157-45b9-86df-74226790674fpoe
f0e77eb5-35fa-47f5-b89e-d1b5ef3c726fpoh
1d1ffc02-fee0-446d-aeac-940ab2864a76pof
```

Just a bunch of guids with a word at the end.  Now, Here's my sample .csv file, with all of the replacements we want to make.

```
OLD,NEW
ham,pork
sam,Frodo
linux,Window
morp,porp
poo,restroom
```

Finally, here is the code to do this as a PowerShell Function.

```
Function Refresh-File {
param($inputCSV,$inputfile)

$file = get-content $inputfile

Foreach ($replacement in (Import-csv $inputCSV)){

    $file = $file -replace $replacement.old,$replacement.New

}
$file | set-content $inputfile

}
```

Call it like this: `Refresh-File -inputCSV T:\replace.csv -inputfile T:\blah.exe`

Here's my .exe file after running this, just the value portions, to show you that it worked:

```
pork
Frodo
tam
turkey
cheese
fork
rice
yummy
Window
porp
restroom
pot
poe
poh
pof
```

Since you'll want to automate this, simply make a new replacement.csv file everyday.  Then run this code.  If you've never written a full PS1 script file before, as a quick summary, copy the function, paste it into notepad or the PowerShell ISE, and then at the last line of the script, put the command syntax to call the function.  Save and enjoy.

Comment: Uh. could I have some context as to why this isn't a viable option?  It absolutely solves OPs question.